# Simple responsive navigation menu

Tags: jquery, css

I created this menu in HTML:

```
<div class="trigger" style="display:none;">menu</div>


<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>            
    </ul>
</div>
```

then I wrote some CSS code to make it look responsive, And I wrote that on 400px the navigation will be hidden and only if you click on the button it will show up, it's working good

the problem is if I click on the menu (on the 400px) to show it and I click again to hide it when I resize the windows to higher dimensions the navigation stays hidden.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b6pdy89u/

What is the best way to create this navigation?

Comment: This code is working better than the one you've sent me, please notice that in the version that you've attached, when you resize the window to lower than 400 then you click on the trigger it shows the menu, then you resize the window bigger than 400 and go back to lower than 400 the menu always open since the first time you click on the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.nav').removeAttr('style');
});
```

As an alternate you can do this. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/b6pdy89u/4/)**

```
$('.trigger').click(function () {
    $('.nav').slideToggle(function () {
        var hidden = $(this).is(':hidden');
        if (hidden)
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, But I don't understand the short version of the if here, is it a short version? can you write a regular if?

Comment: @user4571629 for `if`, `for` etc, if the content inside them are a single line, then there is no need to use `{}`